# codeigniter : can't see my success message in other page

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-flashdata

i have a problem : when click register in my form it is redirect me to the login page but they do not show me this message  .

> "Thank you , you have been registered"

this is a part of my login page "view"

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5 center-block-e">
    <div class="login-page-header">
    <?php echo lang("ctn_304") ?> <?php echo $this->settings->info->site_name ?>
    </div>
    <div class="login-page">
    <?php echo form_open(site_url("login/pro")) ?>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon white-form-bg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo lang("ctn_303") ?>">
        </div><br />
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon white-form-bg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
            <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo lang("ctn_180") ?>">
        </div>
        <p class="decent-margin"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" value="<?php echo lang("ctn_184") ?>"></p>
        <p class="decent-margin"><a href="<?php echo site_url("login/forgotpw") ?>"><?php echo lang("ctn_181") ?></a></p>
```

this is a part of my register page "controller"

```
if (empty($fail)) {
    // Check for any default user groups
    $default_groups = $this->user_model->get_default_groups();
    foreach($default_groups->result() as $r) {
        $this->user_model->add_user_to_group($userid, $r->ID);
    }
    $this->session->set_flashdata("globalmsg", $success);
    redirect(site_url("login"));
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you output your flashdata.

Comment: @u_mulder i have used this in my login page "view"     <?= $this->session->flashdata('globalmsg');?> but it's not working

Comment: then show your code

Comment: You set the flashdata with the variable `$success`. But where is `$success` given a value? Does it have one? If not, then neither will flashdata item "globalmsg".

Comment: @DFriend PLEASE HOW CAN I GIVE $SUCCESS a value and in what file ? please i want short exemple . and really thank you bro .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Note***: make sure you have loaded session library

In login view to show msg use this line of code :

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('globalmsg');?>
```

Code should be like this (use wherever you want to show):

```
<div id="container">
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('globalmsg');?>
    ..........

</div>
</div>
```

*Set your flash data in register page "controller" like this :*

```
$this->session->set_flashdata("globalmsg", 'Thank you , you have been registered');
redirect(site_url("login"));
```

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add container on login page e.g `<div id='globalmsg'></div>` any element where your id should be the which passed to the first parameter passed to the  to append your succes message and second parameter is your message

```
$success = '"Thank you , you have been registered"';

$this->session->set_flashdata("**globalmsg**", $success);
```